# Auto update cell based on time duration passed in another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Need help auto-updating cell based on time passed. 
If cell in G is more than 15
Want to auto-update cell J (from data validation) to "15"

[image]

Time duration is how many days have passed since the application was submitted. 
(Trying to find a job in tech) 
TimeInfo is on column F.

Maybe onEdit(event) would work best, not sure though.

formula is `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(if(Len($N$1),(int($N$1-F3)),)))` 
Pulling (Now) from $N$1

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S-BCDtI535lgT9eZmAiMh-Qwg84zV5oBYDP20B9KhDo/edit?usp=sharing

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: onEdit only triggers on user edits not from actions of formulas or other scripts.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/129744/how-to-trigger-a-script-in-google-sheets-when-a-value-changes

Comment: @Cooper I see what you mean and why the scripts I've been writing haven't been working. Is there a way to convert the formula into another cell were it will recognize it as plain text? text join or cont joint, or something similar, would that work?